# Laravel redirect back with variable not working

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

i am building a laravel aplication and  i have this line of code which  should redirect the user back to form he just submited , with the old input and the result of some operations .

```
 return back()->with(["result" => round($area, 2)])->withInput($request->all());
```

The problem is that i only receive the old input in blade and the `$result` variable is not available in the view.

This is how i try to output the result:

```
<input type="text" name="result" value="{{isset($result)&&old('roofType')==0?$result:''}} &#x33a1; " class="form-control input-sm" >
```

And here is what variables i have in the view after submit:

```
{{ dd(get_defined_vars()['__data']) }}:

array:7 [▼
         "__env" => Factory {#89 ▶}
         "app" => Application {#3 ▶}
         "errors" => ViewErrorBag {#169 ▶}
         "roofName" => "Acoperis intr-o apa"
         "roofType" => "1"
         "roofFolder" => "A1"
         "baseFields" => array:3 [▼
                                  0 => "L"
                                  1 => "l"
                                  2 => "H"
                                  ]
          ]
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem was that I thought that writing 
`return back()->with('bladeVar', $controllerVar)` was the same as `return view('test')->with('bladeVar', $controllerVar);`,but it wasn't .

You cannot echo a variable using blade normal syntax: `{{ $bladeVar }}`, Instead, you have to access the session to get the value: `{{ session('bladeVar') }}`.

After I changed the way I displayed the data all worked as expected.

Comment: return back()->with('something') should be accessed by `session` only.

Comment: Spent a whole precious hour on the crazy stuff until found this. Thank you so much for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is you can not.

If you want to use `with()` then use it with `view()` like:

```
return view('welcome')->with(['name' => 'test']);
```

You can not use `with()` with `back()` and `redirect()`. It won't give you any error but you will not get the variable on the view.

More info: https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#passing-data-to-views

Comment: i got the variable in my view , but not the usual way , i got it via session.

Comment: if I use the return view('welcome') the withImput() is not working anymore. Any idea how I can fix this then?

Comment: What error are you getting? And please add code into question.

Answer (score 1):

```
return redirect()->back()->with('result',round($area, 2))->withInput($request->all());
```

call 
{{Session::get('result')}}
in your blade.

Comment: unfortunately i already tried this solution, and i also tired it again just now , and its not solving my problem ...

Comment: So, If directly not working u can use flash session which is as like as with()       
$request->session()->flash('result', round($area, 2));

Answer (score 0):

```
return view('profile.reset', compact('user'));
```