# why this function don't pass the coupon data to view in PHP Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have created an online store, but there is a problem that when I enter the discount code in, the condition is executed correctly and returns a message of success of the operation, but no data for the entered discount code is returned.

**the check function**

```
public function coupon_check()
    {
        $coupon = Coupon::where('code', request()->post('code'))->first();

        if (isset($coupon) || !empty($coupon)) {
            toast('Successfully !!!', 'success');
            return redirect()->back()->with(['coupon'=>$coupon]);
        } else {
            toast('Not Found !!!', 'error');
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }
```

**in here**

```
            <tr> 
               <td style="color: white">{{__('discount')}}</td>
               <td style="color: white">@if($coupon){{$coupon->discount_value }} 
                 @endif </td> 
            </tr>
```

**when executing this form**

```
       <form action="{{ route('coupons.check') }}" method="POST">
          @csrf
           <input type="text" name="code" class="form-control text-center" placeholder=" 
               {{ __('cupon code') }}">
            <button name="confirm_code" class="btn btn-success col-md">{{ __('Confirm') 
                }}</button>
       </form>
```

Comment: Try to `dd($coupon)` inside the `if` conditional, To see the coupon before return to the view, And everything is well at the controller.

Comment: The `with(['coupon'=>$coupon])` is why you can't access it from your view. Using the `with` function with a redirect passes the coupon into the session. If you want to access the $coupon in your blade view like that, you need to fetch it from the session `{{ session('coupon') }}`.

If you wanted to use the coupon variable in your view without it being in the session, you should `return view('view_name')->with(['coupon' => $coupon])`. Check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45814650/laravel-redirect-back-with-variable-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `with`, you create a session, and to access that session, you should use `session` helper. So change your if statement like this:

```
@if(session('coupon')){{session('coupon')->discount_value }}
```

Comment: Thank you, the process done successfully  by session